# Django add output of model method to serialized object

Tags: python, django, json, django-models, django-serializer

I have a model which has a method to calculate a percentage its containing values consist of when compared to other related child objects:

```
class childModel(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel)

    def percentage(self):
        return 100*float(self.count)/float(self.parent.total_count())
```

When I serialize this object to output in JSON, I'd like to include the value of that percentage method within the JSON output.

I've tried various hacky methods using `model_to_dict` and then adding the value to the dict. This works fine for dumping data, but causes issues when re-loading it as it doesn't store the model key which the Django inbuilt `serializers_serialize` function does when dumping data.

I'm also keen to use the `use_natural_keys` option of `serializers_serialize`, and naturally `model_to_dict` does not include this - I guess I could hackily add this in too, but it seems like I'm very much fighting the system. Any ideas?

Comment: What about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587119/serialize-the-property-methods-in-a-python-class  ?