# Django DRF Model Serailzier - Serialize model property

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

How can I add property of a Model in its JSON made using `django.core.serializers` to return in `AJAX` call?

I have a Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
...
@property
def property_field(self):
    return some_value;
```

Then in views, I send a JSON of this model in an AJAX call. The problem is, I don't know how to send value returned by this property. I tried

```
query_set = MyModel.objects.flter(...)
serializers.serialize('json', query_set, fields=('...', ... , 'a_property'))
```

But this doesn't work. How can I pass the value of this property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there is no easy way to accomplish this without [subclassing your own serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2607242/2040872) as the [default serializer only goes through the db fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587119/serialize-the-property-methods-in-a-python-class#comment2601209_2587616).

Comment: Thanks! The answer you linked to works great! I used it after some changes, based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rdenadai/6095815). I posted my Serializer in an answer

Comment: FYI: This is the related Django bug that was won't fixed in 2007 : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3661

I wonder if its time to revisit that..

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

Previous answer was written a long time ago. There are easier ways to do this now, as expected:

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    property_field = serializers.CharField(
        source="property_field",
        read_only=True,
    )
```

This should add `property_field` property in the serailzed `OrderedDict` which you can return to client

**Usage:**

```py
serializer = MyModelSerializer(MyModel.objects.all())
return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

**Old Answer**

This JSON Serializer should work:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer

class JSONSerializer(Serializer):
    def serialize(self, queryset, attributes, **options):
        self.options = options
        self.stream = options.get("stream", StringIO())
        self.start_serialization()
        self.first = True

        for obj in queryset:
            self.start_object(obj)
            for field in attributes:
                self.handle_field(obj, field)
            self.end_object(obj)
            if self.first:
                self.first = False
        self.end_serialization()
        return self.getvalue()

    def handle_field(self, obj, field):
        self._current[field] = getattr(obj, field)
```

(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2607242/2040872), posted by **Tim Edgar ^** and changed using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rdenadai/6095815))

Usage:

```
json = JSONSerializer().serialize(modelName.objects.all(), ('attr1', 'property1', ...))
```