# How to override GeoDjango GeoJSON Seriliazer to include model properties

Tags: django, geojson, geodjango, django-serializer

This is an offshoot of the generic how can I include properties in a JSON serialization, which is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38253327/4140357

```
from django.core.serializers.base import Serializer as BaseSerializer
from django.core.serializers.python import Serializer as PythonSerializer
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer as JsonSerializer

class ExtBaseSerializer(BaseSerializer):

    def serialize_property(self, obj):
        model = type(obj)
        for field in self.selected_fields:
            if hasattr(model, field) and type(getattr(model,
                field)) == property:
                    self.handle_prop(obj, field)

    def handle_prop(self, obj, field):
        self._current[field] = getattr(obj, field)

    def end_object(self, obj):
        self.serialize_property(obj)

        super(ExtBaseSerializer, self).end_object(obj)


class ExtPythonSerializer(ExtBaseSerializer, PythonSerializer):
    pass


class ExtJsonSerializer(ExtPythonSerializer, JsonSerializer):
    pass
```

How to use it:

```
ExtJsonSerializer().serialize(
    MyModel.objects.all(),
    fields=['field_name_1', 'property_1' ...]
)
```

And it works great for JSON.

How can you do the same thing for [GEODJango's GEJSON serializer](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b014de011b977b733758812df5788dc200bb35ac/django/contrib/gis/serializers/geojson.py)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite straightforward to alter the original answer for JSON to work  with GEOJSON.

You need to change one line in the imports so instead of importing
`from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer as JsonSerializer` you import the GEOJSON one
`from django.contrib.gis.serializers.geojson import Serializer as JsonSerializer`

Here's the full code for ease of cut-n-paste.

```
from django.core.serializers.base import Serializer as BaseSerializer
from django.core.serializers.python import Serializer as PythonSerializer
from django.contrib.gis.serializers.geojson import Serializer as JsonSerializer


class ExtBaseSerializer(BaseSerializer):

    def serialize_property(self, obj):
        model = type(obj)
        for field in self.selected_fields:
            if hasattr(model, field) and type(getattr(model,
                field)) == property:
                    self.handle_prop(obj, field)

    def handle_prop(self, obj, field):
        self._current[field] = getattr(obj, field)

    def end_object(self, obj):
        self.serialize_property(obj)

        super(ExtBaseSerializer, self).end_object(obj)


class ExtPythonSerializer(ExtBaseSerializer, PythonSerializer):
    pass


class ExtJsonSerializer(ExtPythonSerializer, JsonSerializer):
    pass
```

How to use it:

```
ExtJsonSerializer().serialize(
    MyModel.objects.all(),
    fields=['field_name_1', 'property_1' ...]
)
```