# Wagtail: How to get image rendition url and pass it along with other fields in json?

Tags: python, wagtail

I am passing all my model's data to the context of the template to use it in a small vue instance:

```
data = serializers.serialize("json", MyModel.objects.child_of(self).live().public())
```

My model has an image:

```
header = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
```

Now I’d like to add the images rendition url to be able to handle the rendering in my vue app:

```
url = myimage.get_rendition('fill-300x186|jpegquality-60').url
```

But I struggle with the `myimage` part. I am afraid the way I want to solve it won’t work, since I am on the model level and there is no information about an image yet, right? So is there anyway to query/pass an image rendition with my other fields as json?

I am aware that the API can handle image renditons:

```
APIField("header", serializer=ImageRenditionField("fill-300x200|jpegquality-80"))
```

I can't use the API though and only like to mimic that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I came back to this and realized my first answer was garbage. I think what you can do is create a property which get's stored as an attribute.

```
@property
def rendition_url(self):
    url = self.header.get_rendition('fill-300x186|jpegquality-60').url
    return url
```

Then you have to build a custom serializer to parse into JSON.

[Serialize the @property methods in a Python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587119/serialize-the-property-methods-in-a-python-class)

This answer provides a clear example how to do this. The top answer is out of date. Use the next example.